# Запуск проекта с помощью сервера Apache Tomcat в среде разработки Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

К проекту в  Eclipse был добавлен сервер Tomcat v8.5 Server (другую версию также пробовал) и, вроде как, он успешно запускается, но при попытке открыть файл проекта `http://localhost:8080/index.html` возникает ошибка:

> HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено

Type Status Report

Message /index.html

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Если же использовать для запуска путь без указания порта, страница не загружается, отображается сообщение, что сервер отклонил запрос на соединение.
Может кто-то сталкивался? Подскажите, как решить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте http://localhost:8080/host-manager/html, не уверен, что там есть index.html

Comment: При переходе по "http://localhost:8080/host-manager/html" открывается страница  https://prnt.sc/w9lji4  , если же  с этой страницы перейти на localhost, можно увидеть https://prnt.sc/w9llb4  . Что-то не так в настройках сервера?

Comment: Ну сам томкат запустился, тут проблем нет, а что вы пытаетесь дальше сделать? На странице менеджера можно посмотреть приложения, но у вас ни одно приложение не зарегистрировано в данный момент

Comment: В эклипсе есть проект для работы с сервлетами. Индекс находиться по такому пути \MyProject\project-master\src\main\webapp\index.html . Нужно при запуске сервера открыть этот файл в браузере. Но при попытке (http://localhost:8080/index.html) его открыть возникает 404. Запуск сервера выполняется тоже через Эклипс